# Para que serve o “|>” em Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Lendo alguns códigos de [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) eu vejo `|>` ser usado comumente. O que ele significa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O simbolo `|>` é conhecido como o [operador pipe](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2). O operador pipe `|>` é algo de extrema utilidade e que irá certamente melhorar a legibilidade do seu código com Elixir.

Ele básicamente pega a saída da expressão da esquerda e passa como primeiro argumento de uma função à direita.

Digamos que eu não tenha conhecimento do operador pipe e queira multiplicar todos os valores de uma lista por dois, logo em seguida filtrar aqueles que são maiores que 4, nosso código ficará da seguinte maneira:

```
lista = [1, 2 , 3]
Enum.filter(Enum.map(lista, &(&1 * 2)), &(&1 > 4))
```

Caso utilizarmos o operador pipe, nosso exemplo ficará diferente:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
# A lista gerada no primeiro map será o primeiro parametro do filter
Enum.map(lista, &(&1 * 2)) |> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 4))
```

Ou ainda, no iex:

```
[1, 2, 3] |> Enum.map(&(&1 * 2))  |> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 4))
```

E num arquivo:

```
[1, 2, 3] 
|> Enum.map(&(&1 * 2))  
|> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 4))
```

Você pode ler mais sobre o operador pipe e outras caracteristicas da linguagem na [documentação oficial](https://elixir-lang.org/) e no [elixirschool](https://elixirschool.com/pt/lessons/basics/basics/#instalando-elixir)